# C pipe and processes

Tags: c, process, operating-system, pipe, ps

I have a question for this process homework. 
There's a parent process that has two child(the first just print hello) , the second child have another child.
The parent should pass to the child(the second one) the bash command "ps", then it passes through the other child(the grandchild) and this should execute the command.
I first tried to pass just a string to see if I put correct all the the pipe and the relation between parent and child, but it does print correctly the string.

Could you help me for this problem? and also with the bash command as well?

Thanks to everyone who read this

```
int main(){ 

pid_t pid;
int pipefd[2];
char comando[10] ;
pipe(pipefd);



fork();
pid = getpid();

if(pid == 0){ // figlio F1
    printf("C:F1 printing...");
    printf("    HELLO   ");
}else if(pid > 0){//parent
    printf("P: sending command ps to F2\n");        
    comando[10] = "ps";

    close(pipefd[0]);   
    write(pipefd[1],(void*)&comando ,sizeof(comando)  );


    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){//figlio F2
        printf("C:F2 receiving from parent \n");
        close( pipefd[1] );
        read(pipefd[0], (void*)&comando , sizeof(comando));
        printf("C:F2 riceve %s \n",comando);
        pid = fork();
        printf("C:F2 sending %s to F3\n",comando);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        write(pipefd[1], (void*)&comando, sizeof(comando));
        if(pid == 0){
            printf("C:F3 receiving from F2\n");
            close( pipefd[1] );
            read(pipefd[0], (void*)&comando , sizeof(comando));
            //int system(const char *comando);
            printf("C:F3 print %s \n",comando);
        }
    }
}else{
    printf("fork error\n");     
}
wait(NULL);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getpid()` will not return 0 for the child process after a call to `fork()`, it will return the child process's actual PID. You need to check the value returned by `fork()`, not the value returned by `getpid()`.

Comment: The parent must hold open all pipe ends that its child needs to use until *after* it forks that child.  Any that it closes before forking will already be closed in the child when it starts executing.

Comment: Actually i first write pid = fork() also before the first if..is it correct like this?

Comment: Yes, `pid = fork();` will set the `pid` variable to 0 for the child process.

Comment: Ok, now looks like it receive the string from parent to the child and grandchild.. thanks..but now how do I pass a bash command and execute?

Comment: `ps` is not a *bash* command specifically.  It's a command, period.  You can execute it via bash, or via another shell instead.  Or, as I imagine the assignment expects, you can execute it via one of the exec-family functions, such as `execvp()`.

Comment: As for getting the command from parent to grandchild, I can only guess at what the exercise specifies, but it seems likely that that's the point of the pipes.  Certainly that's what I assumed when I first read your question.

Comment: Are you allowed to use [popen()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)?

Comment: Never heard of it actually..but as i read from the man page it looks like is the thing i', searching for this purpose

Comment: I tried to use the popen() but it gives me the segmentation error..what should i put inside the brachets?